# Linker Command Failed With Realm?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, realm

I have installed `Realm` with pods and everything complies. I even have a subclass for two `RLMObjects` that are to be used to save my custom class objects to realms default space.

```
@interface RLNotification : RLMObject

- (instancetype)initWithNotification:(KANotification *)notification;

@property NSString *docID, *userID, *username;
@property NSInteger time, type;

@end


@interface RLProfilePicture : RLMObject

- (instancetype)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image;

@property (nonatomic) NSString *userID;
@property (nonatomic) NSData *imageData;
@property NSInteger timeLastUpdated;


@end
```

---

#### PROBLEM

When I go to use these though, in **any** class, like such:

```
NSLog(@"test: %@", [RLNotification allObjects]);

RLNotification *noti = RLNotification.new;
noti.userID = @"hey";
noti.username = @"nope!";

[RLMRealm.defaultRealm addObject:noti];

NSLog(@"test2: %@", [RLNotification allObjects]);
```

I get this warning...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RLNotification", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AnyClassName.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

What on earth am I doing wrong / need to change?....

Comment: Make sure these files is being compiled as part of the build phase.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was an anomaly. I removed `Realm` from my pod file, cleaned, deintegrated, updated Cocoa, installed, the whole process.

Did this easily 4 times, 5th time worked. ‍♂️